# stop a curl transfer in the middle

Tags: php, curl, callback

i could only think of curl_close() from one of the callback functions.
but php throws a warning:

PHP Warning:  curl_close(): Attempt to close cURL handle from a callback.

any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You are going to need to post more code.

Comment: could you add some more information please, e.g. **why** you want to close the transfer before being finished

Answer (score 4):

you can return false or something what is not length of currently downloaded data from callback function to abort curl

Comment: +1, a few more details from the PHP manual for curl_setopt : CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION The name of a callback function where the callback function takes two parameters. The first is the cURL resource, and the second is a string with the data to be written. The data must be saved by using this callback function. It must return the exact number of bytes written or the transfer will be aborted with an error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that needed me to be able to stop a curl transfer in the middle. This is easily in my personal top ten of 'dirty hacks that seem to work' of all time.

Create a curl read function that knows when it's time to cancel the upload.

```
function curlReadFunction($ch, $fileHandle, $maxDataSize){

    if($GLOBALS['abortTransfer'] == TRUE){
        sleep(1);
        return "";
    }
    return fread($fileHandle, $maxDataSize);
}
```

And tell Curl to stop if the data read rate drops too low for a certain amount of time.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, 'curlReadFunction');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1024);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 5);
```

This will cause the curl transfer to abort during the upload. Obviously not ideal but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that is taking too long to execute the curl, you could set a time, example

```
<?php
$c = curl_init('http://slow.example.com/');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
$page = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
echo $page;
```

Comment: no sir, i use a more advanced algorithms than "taking too long to execute", and thus i need to kill it when my algorithm decides so.