# Stop a PHP Curl Download

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to find a way to stop an active PHP Curl download. I am downloading large files from a remote server and sometimes I would like to cancel the download after it has started. I have tried returning false within `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION`, however that did not work. I also tried deleting the file that was being downloaded, and that did not work either (web stats showed the download was continuing).

The below code is triggered via a quick ajax call:

```
$ch = curl_init( $file->url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $targetFile); //save the file to here
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function($resource, $download_size, $downloaded_size, $upload_size, $uploaded_size) use ($download_id) {
  if ( $download_size == 0 ) {
      $progress = 0;
  } else {
      $progress = round( $downloaded_size * 100 / $download_size );
  }

  // if download complete trigger completed function
  if($progress == 100) {
     self::DownloadCompleted($download_id);
  }

});
$curl = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877930/stop-a-curl-transfer-in-the-middle :)

Comment: Similar problem. No solution was posted. And it was from 6 years ago....

Comment: did you try suggestion about CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION (`It must return the exact number of bytes written or the transfer will be aborted with an error`)?

Comment: How about this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444123/shut-down-a-curl-request). See Anthony's answer.

Comment: Return a non-zero value from the progress function to abort the transfer.  False is a zero value so it won't work.  `return 1;` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to return a non-zero value in the `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` function, as per drew010 in the comment.

To get this done I added a check within the function to see if a file exists, if it does the function returns 1 and aborts. I just create a file in the directory with the same name as the download ID when I want to cancel the download. It works well for me.

```html
$ch = curl_init( $file->url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $targetFile); //save the file to here
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function($resource, $download_size, $downloaded_size, $upload_size, $uploaded_size) use ($download_id) {
  
  //if the file exists, the download is aborted
  if(file_exists('path/to/directory/cancel.'.$download_id)) {
    Self::CleanupCancelledDownload; //function to clean up the partially downloaded file, etc.
    return 1; //returning a non-zero value cancels the CURL download.
  }
});
$curl = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: You might want to throw in `clearstatcache` inside the callback function, because the result of `file_exists` can be cached.